# Zebra Table using css and html?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I need to do this table in css:

[image: I need to do this table in css]

I need help please, I  don't know how to do it.

Comment: Learn HTML and CSS and you can do it

Comment: ー1 for no effort shown.

Comment: This site is meant to HELP developers, not to REPLACE them

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:nth-of-type(odd)` to do this.

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {background-color: green;}
```

Comment: Works in IE and Firefox in the year 2018. I guess (but don't know) that this can be used today.

Answer (score 0):

Replace data as pleased, ideally some code on your end would be better. Give the class `highlight` to highlighted `tr`s. Note this example includes bootstrap 3 min CSS.

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="highlight">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="highlight">
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```